# How to test callback argument react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jestjs, enzyme

I have a react native component that looks like:

```
export class Estimate extends PureComponent {
  setRef =
    (ref) => {
      this.estimateForm = ref
    }

  render () {
    const { onPress } = this.props
    return (
      <Form
        name="estimateForm"
        ref={this.setRef}
      >
        <Actions style={{ alignItems: 'flex-end' }}>
          <Button
            type="text"
            style={{ marginBottom: -em(0.5) }}
            onPress={() => onPress(this.estimateForm.values)}
            title={t('estimateShippingAndTax')}
          />
          <TextInput
            placeholder={t('postalCode')}
            name="estimate"
            style={{ width: 100 }}
            validate="postalCode"
          />
        </Actions>
      </Form>
    )
  }
}
```

my jest/enzyme test looks like:

```
let obj
let onPressFunction
describe('Estimate', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    onPressFunction = jest.fn()
    obj = shallow(<Estimate onPress={onPressFunction} />)
  })

  test('Text gets returned with onPress', () => {
    console.log(obj.html())
    const value = { values: { estimate: '61606' } }
    obj.instance().setRef(value)
    obj.find('Button').first().simulate('onPress')
    expect(onPressFunction).toHaveBeenCalledWith('61606')
  })
})
```

I cant seem to get my test to pass even though my component works as expected. My test fails with:

Expected mock function to have been called with:
      ["61606"]
    But it was not called.

Comment: I am passing the entire payload as I am yet to add more elements to the form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Enzyme test should simulate the `press` event, not an `onPress` event. The event name is "press".

```
obj.find('Button').first().simulate('press')
```

Looking at your tags, this is a React Native project, and [this thread on the Enzyme repo](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/991) recommends trying calling the method directly instead of relying on `simulate`:

```
obj.find('Button').first().props().onPress()
```

Comment: Thanks that was it :)